# Not able to display ringtones from /system/media/audio/ringtones

Tags: android, android-alarms, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I am using following code to display ringtones :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION | RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
        RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
```

But dialog is showing alarms from /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones directory. 
Is there a way to access ringtones from /system/media/audio/ringtones directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the permission added onto the manifest

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
               />
    ...
</manifest>
```